# Bash prompt scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to follow a guide found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-bash-prompt-on-a-linux-vps), but I do not like what I see as a cop out. In the script they set `PS1` to

```
PS1="<code> `cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'` <more code>"
```

My problem with this is I would like to know if it is possible to write it with single quotes like:

```
PS1='<code> `cat /proc/loadavg | awk \'{print $1}\'` <more code>'
```

So it is evaluated every time I run the command, not just the once. It seems the presence of the single quotes in awk are forcing me to use double quotes. I would like to have  this run after every prompt and I have another awk tidbit of code I would like to run here as well.

If this would be too cumbersome for bash to do, then I'm fine not having it, it's more for proof of concept anyways.

Comment: While not a solution to the quoting issues, you could use `cut` instead of `awk` to avoid needing single quotes.

Comment: Wouldn't it solve your problem to just escape the `$` in the double-quoted version? i.e. `'{print \$1}'`

Comment: @izzy cut would not work for the other scenario I  had in mind, although I did try using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put a single quote into single quotes, you have to end the single quotes, insert the quote, and start single quotes again:

```
PS1='$(code | awk '\''{print $1}'\'')'
# or
PS1='$(code | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"')'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that you could simply concatenate them as such.